# Text not showing in text box

Tags: c#, winforms

`orderNo` is increased by 1 everytime the createOrder form is opened. **The `orderNo` is not displaying in the `textbox11`.** I have to enter something into the textbox for it to change automatically to the counter.

```
public int orderNo;

private void textBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox11.Text = Convert.ToString(orderNo);
}
```

**EDIT** - put code into `form_load`, but the counter seems not to change once `createOrder` form is opened.

Comment: You need to show us some relevant code.

Comment: Shouldn't it be under the form load event rather than the textbox changed event?

Comment: debug is textBox11_TextChanged being fired? what would be changing the text box?

Comment: Why do you put the code in the textBox11_TextChanged event?? It belong in the form1_Load event!

Comment: Thanks all, question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `textBox_TextChanged` is not going to be called by the text box until user (or other piece of code) changes it's contents.  Wherever you set `orderNo` should update the text.  Do something like the following

```
private int orderNo;
public int OrderNo
{
    get { return this.orderNo; }
    set { this.orderNo = value; textBox11.Text = Convert.ToString(orderNo); }
}
```

And then in your code, everywhere you set `orderNo`, change it to use `OrderNo` to set it through a property.

Answer (score 0):

Josh is correct if you want to make the functionality you wish  on `Load_Form event` add:

```
textBox11.Text = Convert.ToString(orderNo);
```

or add a second `textbox` and set:

```
textBox2.Text=orderNo.ToString();
textBox2.Visible=False;
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox11.Text = Convert.ToString(orderNo);
}
```